# Hard disk spins up, head moves twice (and beeps), then it stops

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

My main HDD died about a month ago in the middle of the W10 upgrade from W7. Unfortunately I can't afford any data recovery service, so I just sucked up and swapped with an SDD.
The HDD starts spinning, then I hear two beeps, and it stops right after.

I tried checking different things, SATA cable connections, different SATA ports, different power plugs, upgrading the BIOS, but nothing changed, and my conclusion is that the issue is with the drive itself.
Since it is as good as dead right now - the HDD is not detected even by the BIOS, as in, it does not appear in the setup screen with the other HDDs - I tried opening it to see if it was a stuck head or something like that, but it isn't. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDLOF1EPz4M) video is not mine, but my HDD has the exact same behaviour.
What could the issue be? Even making it work for a couple hours would be great, just to get some data off it.

Comment: Opening it up was a bad idea as any dust that got in could now damage the platter when it spins and make the data unrecoverable. I doubt it is practical to repair it yourself; some people have tried swapping over the circuit board from an identical unit but it may just cause yet more damage and wouldn't help if the problem is mechanical anyway. If you really need that data then it might be best just to save up and try to get a reputable data recovery company to attempt it.

Comment: I know, it was a last ditch solution, as I said I don't have the money to afford data recovery services. I made peace with it, but as there was still this door opened, I wanted to try. Now I'd like to identify this issue, maybe I can do something about it.

Comment: Too late now. You killed it, even if it was only wounded before you opened it. Professional data recovery *might* be able to get some of the data back, but they will make no guarantees, especially as you opened it. At least you learned not one, but two useful lessons. 1) Never open a hard drive & 2) what backups are for :/

Comment: I can't see how it's dead only now to be honest. I know the dust particles can and will damage the discs inside when opened in a not adequate room, but the issue is still there and it's the same as it was before - two beeps, stops spinning. Even disregarding the status of the data inside the problem hasn't changed and I'd like to know what it is that makes the disk stop spinning. Some sort of power failure? What could the beeps be? The heads bumping into the center ridge of the discs? How would one go trying to fix it?

Comment: Too late. There is ***no*** DIY fix now.

Comment: Not convinced in the least, it's not a logical conclusion and you haven't explained why it wouldn't work anymore after opening. I've seen opened HDD working, and I'm pretty sure if there's a fix to this problem it's possible to make it work again, so I'll wait for someone knowleadgeable to answer this, hopefully. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People too quickly moan about data recovery services and how a drive instantly dies the moment you open it. Don't listen to those naysayers and their technical expertise.

In my humble opinion ( and too much damn reading into this ) there are three components that fail.

1. The PCB, the soothing green board on the back of your disk with the
   occasional burnt mark. It can be burnt, because circuits get hot. It
   can have a short circuit, which really just burns things. It can
   have a firmware bug, which again, burns things usually. And it can
   simply just get tired and old. And burn up because things start to
   short out. Essentially these burn. These can be replaced, but need
   to have a component soddered from the original PCB. Not for the
   faint of heart.[This is a good read on the subject](http://www.donordrives.com/)
2. The motor can burn. As stated before, things burn. And the motor that makes the disk spin is no exception. As far as I know, it doesn't get better. More on this later.
3. The robot arm. This is the bit that reads and writes your data. It's a little antennae like thing that is controlled by an electromagnet. If it burns or breaks you're toast. More on this later.
4. Four! Four things can go wrong with a drive. The disk. If you open the case, you introduce blah blah dust and grime and it scratches the surface.blah. Data can still be read. Only the damaged area prevents data to be read/written. And even then.. it can be debatable. Don't quit until you try is all I advocate. Especially if the data is expendable.ish.
   Now, if a motor/arm dies, you open up the drive take out the disks from the platter and place them on a new enclosure. Has to be exactly the same model. And you might need to replace a certain [rom](https://www.hddzone.com/fix_hard_drive_pcb_board.html) containing component.
   If your arm gets stuck or dies.. Some people on the odd parts of the internet claimed that the position of the drive can help. Violent shaking. To unstuck the arm you see. And.. Even freezing.  I've tried those. With.. questionable results. But to be fair freezing electronics is a hallmark of DIY electronics quickfix.

So there you have it. Four things that can go wrong with your hard drive and what you can do about it.
Mind you, this is **NOT** guaranteed to secure save or rescue your data. Weight your options. Evaluate the cost-benefit and do a risk analysis. And then do it anyway because why not?

*Good luck!*

Comment: Kinda late, but it's the one answer I would've wanted to read back then. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, have a good one!